Error 404 when accessing route on express server with React and Axios
I am developing a web application with React on the frontend and Express on the backend. When trying to access a specific path on my Express server from my React app, I get a 404 error.
Relevant code:
In App.js (frontend):
useEffect(() => {
  searchUsers();
}, [connected]);

const fetchUsers = async () => {
  attempt {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/me', {
      headers: {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    setUsers(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting users:', error);
    console.error('Axios error:', error.response);
  }
};

In server.js (backend):
app.use('/api', require('./routes/auth'));

I have tried to indicate this command: app.get('/api/auth/me', (req, res) => {
res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello from server" });
}); to see if it took me to "hello from server", but it keeps taking me to the form and showing the same error. It should be noted that I have put: 'Accept': 'application/json', in the headers of my App.js.

What's inside require('./routes/auth')?

Within auth.js, it tells me that the Express server is not handling the following route: router.get('/me', authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
attempt {
res.status(200).json(userreq);
} catch (error) {
res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error getting user information', error: error.message });
}
});
